# MySQL - Ayuda creando un procedimiento almacenado DELETE

Tags: mysql

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar MySQL y necesito ayuda creando un PA para que borre campos de 2 tablas a la vez, esto el lo que intentè y no funcionò

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BorradoCascada
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @IDalumno INT();
delete FROM alumno where IDalumno = @IDalumno;
DELETE FROM matricula WHERE IDalumno = @IDalumno;
END
```

Comment: Borra sin inner join, en dos sentencias delete separadas.

Comment: Hola, me sale este error: 
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'BEGIN DECLARE         @IDalumno INT()' en la linea 2

Comment: déjame pensar un momento...

Comment: Te faltan puntos y comas al final de los deletes. Pruébalo.

Comment: Listo, los agregue pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, serà que estoy declarando mal? (No se bien como se declara en MySQL)

Comment: has cambiado los delimitadores? mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

Comment: delimiter $$ CREATE PROCEDURE BorradoCascada(pIDalumno INT) BEGIN DELETE FROM matricula WHERE IDalumno = pIDalumno; DELETE FROM alumno WHERE IDalumno = pIDalumno; END$$ delimiter ; dime que es lo que esta haciendo aquí por favor no lo entiendo

Answer (score 1):

Veo por lo menos 3 problemas que hay que corregir:

1. Has definido una variable local `@IDalumno`, pero en realidad, tu intención debe ser de definirla como un parámetro de tu procedure.
2. Porque tu procedure incluye puntos y comas, debes redifinir el `DELIMITER` antes y después de crear tu procedure para evitar que MySQL interprete los puntos y comas como el final de la sentencia `CREATE PROCEDURE`.
3. Le haces un `DELETE` a `alumno` antes de `matricula`. Si has definido un foreign key entre las 2 tablas, lo que sería lo correcto, entonces el `DELETE` a `alumno` va a fallar porque aun existirían registros en `matricula` que apuntan a `alumno`. Lógicamente, debes borrar los registros hijos antes del padre.

Versión corregida:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE BorradoCascada(pIDalumno INT)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM matricula WHERE IDalumno = pIDalumno;
  DELETE FROM alumno WHERE IDalumno = pIDalumno;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Lo puedes ejecutar de esta forma:

```
CALL BorradoCascada(10);
```

---

Alternativemente, pudieras optar por definir (o redifinir si ya existe) un foreign key entre las 2 tablas que automáticamente borra los registros correspondientes en `matricula` cuando borras un registro en la tabla `alumno`. Esto evitaría que tengas que definir este procedure. Simplemente efectuarías el `DELETE` con la tabla `alumno`, y esto se encargaría de borrar los registros en `matricula` de forma automática.

Esto lo puedes lograr con un `FOREIGN KEY .. ON DELETE CASCADE`. Ejemplo:

```
alter table matricula
add constraint matricula_fk
foreign key (IDalumno)
references alumno (IDalumno)
on delete cascade;
```

Entonces, en vez de ejecutar un procedure, simplemente ejecutarías el `DELETE` siguiente:

```
DELETE FROM alumno WHERE IDalumno = 10;
```

Comment: DELETE FROM alumno WHER IDalumno = pIDalumno; falta 'E' en Where, pero está bien

Comment: Gracias @Pedro. Me di cuenta hace unos minutos y lo corregí. Tal vez tengas que hacer un Refresh para ver mi corrección.

Comment: @Pedro: Me acabo de dar cuenta que había otro lugar que no había visto. Gracias.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS! @sstan , La verdad estoy comenzando a usar el MySQL y la razon por la que necesitaba el PA era para ejecutarlo desde PHP, tengo una ultima pregunta, el (10) vendria siendo el parametro IDalumno?

    CALL BorradoCascada(10);

Comment: @Gammath: `10` es el valor del ID del alumno que quieres borrar. Es solo un ejemplo. Tu le pasas el valor que quieres.

Comment: @sstan, Gracias! te darìa +1 pero no tengo reputacion :c

Comment: Pero sí puedes aceptar la respuesta si así lo deseas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)